# How to send data to and from the browser with a Qt HTML5 Application

Tags: qt, qtwebkit

None of the tutorials available online show how to create a Qt HTML5 application. Ideally, I just need a way to send data (a string will do) between webkit and Qt.

When I create a Qt HTML5 Application It generates

1. myApp.pro
2. html5applicationviewer.pri // comments say dont touch this file
3. html5applicationviewer.h // comments say dont touch this file
4. html5applicationviewer.cpp // comments say dont touch this file
5. main.cpp
6. index.html

So how do I add a function in C++ to communicate with the browser and how do I add a function in the browser to communicate with C++?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[This example](http://blogs.kde.org/2009/07/05/adding-custom-objects-qt-webkit) is old but still work and is very simple and clean.

Also you may want to take a look to [qtwebkit-bridge](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtwebkit-bridge.html) and the [tutorial](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/webkit-imageanalyzer.html).

**edit**

add a file called `myclass.h`

```
#include "html5applicationviewer/html5applicationviewer.h"

class MyClass : public Html5ApplicationViewer
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyClass(QWidget *parent=0);
private slots:
    void addToJavaScript();
public slots:
    QString test(const QString &param);
};
```

add a file called `myclass.cpp`

```
#include <QDebug>
#include <QGraphicsWebView>
#include <QWebFrame>

#include "myclass.h"

MyClass::MyClass(QWidget *parent) : Html5ApplicationViewer(parent) {
    QObject::connect(webView()->page()->mainFrame(),
            SIGNAL(javaScriptWindowObjectCleared()), SLOT(addToJavaScript()));
}

void MyClass::addToJavaScript() {
    webView()->page()->mainFrame()->addToJavaScriptWindowObject("MyClass", this);
}

QString MyClass::test(const QString &param) {
    qDebug() << "from javascript " << param;
    return QString("from c++");
}
```

in your `.pro` add

```
SOURCES += main.cpp myclass.cpp
HEADERS += myclass.h
```

in your `.html` add

```
try {
    alert(MyClass.test("test string"));
} catch(err) {
    alert(err);
}
```

in your `main.cpp` add include:

```
#include "myclass.h"
```

and change:

```
Html5ApplicationViewer viewer;
```

to:

```
MyClass viewer;
```

Comment: Not sure why this answer wasn't accepted yet!! thanks, it was of a great help for me, I don't think addToJavaScriptWindowObject is documented for Html5ApplicationViewer the way you described. great :)

Comment: I finally got back to this project and your instructions worked perfectly. First try!

Comment: perfect answer!