# Qt HTML5 Application - passing complex object between Javascript and C++

Tags: c++, html, qt

Based on a SO question, I was able to successfully pass primitive variables between Javascript and C++.  Ideally, I would like to be able to send complex objects.  I read through the documentation but didn't find anything related to this.  I could JSON encode my object and send it through that way but I was wondering if there was a Qt supported way of doing this.

Here is the original question that I referenced: [How to send data to and from the browser with a Qt HTML5 Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18475794/how-to-send-data-to-and-from-the-browser-with-a-qt-html5-application)

Comment: How about using [JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612787/converting-an-object-to-a-string) to serialize and deserialize the objects? Qt can even deserialize it for you as of [Qt 5.2](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/json.html).

Comment: I thought about that.  I will go this route if I cannot find anything else.  Even though Qt has libraries to help, I wasn't looking forward to writing JSON serialization code for 500+ objects.

Comment: That's when [Metaprogramming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaprogramming) comes in.